# Why is my band-pass filter self-oscillating?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, active-filter, band-pass

I built a bi-quad filter based on the AD8054 (consist of four AD8051 op amps) following exactly the [AD8051/8054 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8051_8052_8054.pdf).

After I power up my op-amp, the filter entered a steady self-oscillating even without an input signal.

The self-oscillating signal is stable at around 25MHz, even after I swapped the values of capacitors and resistor for the filter. Could you please help me troubl shoot and let me know how to address this issue?

[image: Schematic][image: PCB][image: AD8054]

Comment: Please show your full actual circuit that you used to design the PCB. Ensure that power supply information is not missing and please explain what signal generator you used and how stuff was grounded.

Answer (score 1):

> *after I power up my op-amp, the filter entered a steady
> self-oscillating even without given an input signal. The
> self-oscillating signal is stable at around 25MHz, even after I
> swapped the values of capacitors and resistor for the filter. Could
> you please help me trouble shoot and let me know how to address this
> issue?*

- You don't appear to have pins 3, 5, 10 and 12 connected in your PCB (showstopper): -

[image]

- The PCB should have a ground plane covering all unused portions of the component side of the board to provide a low impedance path. The ground plane should be removed from the area near the input pins to reduce parasitic capacitance (from data sheet). You don't have that.
- The specified high speed performance of the AD8051/AD8052/AD8054 requires careful attention to board layout and component selection. Proper RF design techniques and low parasitic component selection are necessary (from data sheet). It doesn't look like you have done this.
- Chip capacitors should be used for supply bypassing. One end should be connected to the ground plane and the other within 3 mm of each power pin (from data sheet). You don't appear to have done this.
- The feedback resistor should be located close to the inverting input pin to keep the parasitic capacitance at this node to a minimum. Parasitic capacitance of less than 1 pF at the inverting input can significantly affect high speed performance (from data sheet). You don't appear to have done this.

There are possibly other PCB anomalies. The op-amp you are using is extremely sensitive to non-compliances (as mentioned above). For instance, it runs normally very close to oscillation judging by the transient response: -

[image]

I think you have just pushed things too far.

Comment: Hi Andy, first of all thanks for your reply. Really appreciate that. Although I did ground the front and bottom planes, with pins such as 3,5,10 and 12. I'm just really confused how is the op-amp self oscillating with such a high voltage (>2V) even without given an input signal.

Comment: You should try connecting the input node to 0 volts instead of leaving it open @BenjaminZ

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your help! I'm only showing only part of PCB layout. In the actual design, the input is connected to my signal source with signal to be filtered. Also, I'm wondering could you please help me explain "Chip capacitors should be used for supply bypassing. One end should be connected to the ground plane and the other within 3 mm of each power pin"? I'm using 2.2uF decoupling capacitors for V+ and V-, with one pin connect to power and other pin to the ground. I thought that I have already done that bypassing part with these decoupling caps? thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the band pass output directly attached to your output connector. That invites instability from reactive loads. Series termination with 50Ω is desirable for things like this.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your advice! I'll definitely add that for my design! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say exactly what is wrong, but the basics are that at 25MHz you are seeing >= unity gain and enough phase shift through the 3 stages to feedback an additive signal into the input.   So a little noise at 25MHz will gradually build to a full resonance.     Now the middle stage will actually pass 25MHz - the amplifiers are fast enough to do >25MHz with reasonable voltage swing.   The first and last stages, in theory have less than unity gain at 25MHz (the 50pF should be about 100ohms at 25MHz, so you have 100/2000 = x0.05 gain).

So the question is what would make either of these not behave according to the ideal?

Well the datasheet tells you to be very careful of parasitic capacitance at the inputs - you've flooded GND right up to these pins - so perhaps that's part of the problem.

Also any series inductance added to the feedback loops will cause gain to increase with frequency.  Perhaps the loops from VOUT via the C1 (or C2) back to IN- are mildly inductive because of discontinuities in the GND plane (we cannot see those in your post).  Impossible to say.

Finally, the decoupling caps aren't going to be great at 25MHz, so you have the possibility that the V+/V- nodes are part of the problem!

If you have a two channel scope you should be able to see the phase shift and effective gain across each stage - that will perhaps let you see which of the three stages is behaving badly (my guess, all three ;-)).

Not an answer as such, but too long for a comment.

Comment: Hi Robin, first of all thank you very much for your feedback and help! I do have a quick question though. The data sheet tells me to be careful with the parasitic capacitance at the inputs, and I grounded entire top and bottom PCB planes except all non-inverting pins of AD8054 (which are pins 2,6,9 in this case). Yet you mentioned I flooded GND right up to these pins, could you please help me explain what do you mean by that and how should I further avoid the parasitic capacitance for this case? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: We cannot see from your post exactly where GND flood goes.  I assume that it goes everywhere except pins and nets that aren't gnd.  So it's close to 2, 6 and 9.  Also you have GND underneath.  The pin creates a mini capacitor.  The pin and solder pad are one 'plate' and the GND copper everywhere else is the other plate.  There's also some cap formed between nets.

Comment: So I would be tempted to remove L1 gnd floods, connect all GND net pins to L2 with a via.  You could do that with a Dremel if you have steady hand.   I haven't thought about it in depth, but possibly some repositioning of the R and C elements will reduce coupling.  Finally consider whether some other arrangement of the 4 opamps would be better routing.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate that!

Comment: One further thing occurred to me.  The GND flood on L1 forms part of multiple parasitic caps and so creates a pin-cap-cap-pin sort of circuit that might conduct at 25MHz ... it's a minefield 